# getting below error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparison

code snippet :

```
public static List sortReports(List myList) {
    Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
            ReportUebersichtParameter o1 = (ReportUebersichtParameter) obj1;
            ReportUebersichtParameter o2 = (ReportUebersichtParameter) obj2;
            int value = o1.getSortCriteria().compareTo(o2.getSortCriteria());
            if (-1 == value) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (1 == value) {
                return -1;
            }
            return o1.getTitel().compareTo(o2.getTitel());
        }
    });
    return myList;
}
```

not able to get solution. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my compare methd throw IllegalArgumentException sometimes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458633/why-does-my-compare-methd-throw-illegalargumentexception-sometimes)

Comment: Can you please edit your question containing the whole code?